# VSCodeにて、Kivyのコード作成中、１行目に何を入力してもエラーの赤下線が表示される

Tags: python, vscode, kivy

タイトルの通りなのですが、Pythonのkivyを使用したアプリケーション作成を勉強したいと思いサンプルコードを入力しているのですが、Kvファイル？の１行目が必ずエラー表示となってしまいます。`#` を使用したコメントでもエラーとなります。

ですが、.pyのファイルを実行するとなんの問題もなく実行されます。

このエラーは無視しても良いのでしょうか？
１つだけエラーが残り続けるのも気持ち悪いので何とかしたいと思うのですが。

よろしくお願いします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: oririさんの回答にしたがい、１行目にヘッダーを入力したらエラー表示が無くなりました！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kv ファイルは, Kivyヘッダーで始まります

```
#:kivy `1.0`

# content here
```

(… とか `#:kivy 1.0.9` とか)
(バージョンは使用している Kivy言語バージョン)

参考: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html

確認する方法は以下の通り

```py
import kivy
print(kivy.__version__)
```

---

VS Codeの Kivy拡張に何使ってるか不明だけど
[Kivyのこの拡張](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BattleBas.kivy-vscode) なら, 設定でコントロールできそう